# Setup for Python-Tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

I am new to Python so this question is to get a right direction. What I wish to do is write an application that automatically replies to the queries sent to my Twitter handle. I am using Tweepy for this. My steps are as follows:

1. Listen to any tweets that have mention of my handle
2. Collect the tweet and analyse it
3. Build an automated reply
4. Post a reply on Twitter

I have to connect some web service for steps 2 and 3 and get back a JSON response.

My question is about the right setup. Do you guys think that a standalone Tweepy application would be able to handle this at production level? Or should I go for some server implementation for this? If it is second, can you people point me to some links how I can do that? I am quite new to Python.

Answer (score 1):

Using tweepy streaming an example I found [here](http://peter-hoffmann.com/2012/simple-twitter-streaming-api-access-with-python-and-oauth.html) you can edit the filter to search for "@yourhandle".

You can gain access to the person who tweeted by adding:

```
class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        print status.text
        print status.user.screen_name #<----------------THIS LINE
```

Will show you who tweeted you. You can next try to update status using:

```
api.update_status("my update", in_reply_to_status_id = tweetid)
```

The tweet ID can be gotten using:

```
status.id
```

The code should look like:

```
import tweepy
consumer_key = "xxx"
consumer_secret = "xxx"
access_key = "xxx"
access_secret = "xxx"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        print status.text
        print status.user.screen_name
        api.update_status("Insert Auto Reply Text Here", in_reply_to_status_id = status.id)

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered error with status code:', status_code
        return True # Don't kill the stream

    def on_timeout(self):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Timeout...'
        return True # Don't kill the stream

sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener())
sapi.filter(track=['@rishi'])
```

You will need to create a [dev](https://dev.twitter.com/) twitter account for this to work and input your own security tokens. I currently cant test writing to timelines as mine is read-only.